# How to convert multi-object associative JSON array into Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, json, associative-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

I am pulling a multi-object associative array out of PHP.  An example is below:

```
$displayArray[] = array("Name"=>"Joe", "Important"=>"1", "Group"=>"Family");
$displayArray[] = array("Name"=>"Jane", "Important"=>"0", "Group"=>"Family");
echo json_encode($displayArray);
```

Using AJAX, the returned JSON string is so:

```
[{"Name":"Joe","Important":"1","Group":"Family"},{"Name":"Jane","Important":"0","Group":"Family"}]
```

I would like to convert this JSON data into a Javascript array.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Your second code sample is as a JS array

Comment: Hmm.  So how do I loop through this please.

Comment: You  can use JSON.parse() to do so. Keep in mind that you may need to polyfill this for use in older browsers
.

Comment: google it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Comment: How are you getting this JSON string into your JavaScript page?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, he's using AJAX.

Comment: I use ajax to pull back "echo json_encode($displayArray);".  I still don't see how I can loop thru the keys and values :(

Comment: @Jeremy: Show us your AJAX code.  You probably just need to add `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Jeremy, use JSON.parse() like m90 said.

Comment: Your question really appears to be how to pass data from the server (PHP) to client (JavaScript), and how to parse that data (and you've chosen to use JSON as the format).  We need to see your AJAX to help with that.

Comment: @Jeremy, are you opposed to using a library like jQuery? If not, this gets real simple.

Comment: @JonathanM: For JSON parsing???

Comment: @IHateLazy, for doing the whole AJAX call, including the JSON parsing.

Comment: Here is my AJAX:  var myArray = $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
        url: 'ReadToggle.php',
        dataType:'json',
        async: false
        }).responseText;

Comment: @Jeremy: If you're already using jQuery, then since you have `dataType:"json"`, it's already parsed if you access it in a callback... but you shouldn't be doing `async: false`. You should learn to use callbacks and deal with asynchronous code.

Comment: @Jeremy, yeah you're already using jQuery. In your `success:` segment just put a `function(myObject) { etc. etc. }` and the object will be in `myObject`. Don't use `async:false`.

Comment: Thanks Everyone.  Ernie below sorted it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using jQuery.  The return from [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) isn't the object you're echo back to the browser via PHP.  Instead, you can access the returned data using the success callback, e.g.:

```
var myData;

$.ajax({ type: 'POST', 
       url: 'ReadToggle.php', 
       dataType:'json', 
       async: false })
       success: function(data) {
                    myData = data;
       }
})
```

You can then parse myData like a standard javascript object, e.g.:

```
myData[index]
```

I think most people tend to write their code to handle the returned object in the success function itself, e.g.:

```
var myData;

$.ajax({ type: 'POST', 
       url: 'ReadToggle.php', 
       dataType:'json', 
       async: false })
       success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data[0]);
       }
})
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks Ernie.  I looped so:    for(var index in myData) {
    document.write( 'Name' + " : " + myData[index]['Name'] + "<br />");
    document.write( 'Important' + " : " + myData[index]['Important'] + "<br />");
    document.write( 'Group' + " : " + myData[index]['Group'] + "<br />");
  }

Comment: @Jeremy glad to help.  Like I said, most people put that into the actually success function, rather than using a separate var and code external to the .ajax() call.